# Ajax Call Not Making Calls To Server Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, at.js

I'm trying to make a request using a third party program but it isn't working, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The response just isn't being sent at all. I tried ordering the dependencies in order, placing the scripts at the top and the code after the form but it just isn't making the calls through XHR in console.

Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search = request('name');
        return User::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")
            ->take(5)
            ->pluck('name');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/api/users', 'Api\UserController@index');
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $('#body').atwho({
            at: "@",
            delay: 500,
            callbacks: {
                remoteFilter: function (query, callback) {
                    //$.getJSON('/api/users', { name: query }, function (usernames) {
                    //    console.log('hey');
                    //    callback(usernames);
                    //});
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url: '/api/users',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            name: query,
                            _token: {{csrf_token()}}
                        },
                        success: function (usernames) {
                            callback(usernames);
                            console.log('hey');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log('error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

It works fine here

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.atwho.css">
</head>
<body>
    <textarea type="" id="inputor"></textarea>

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.atwho.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#inputor').atwho({
        at:"@",
        data: ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Anne']
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there `script` file and `css` file included correctly in your laravel project?

Comment: I think so, I've called it from my folder, in the order it is needed (i.e. Caret.js needed before Atwho.js). I placed it at the top, also at the bottom, I don't know what's wrong. I feel like I'm calling it just like I'm calling it in the research project.

Comment: Please check `inspect ` first and see try to identify what's wrong

Comment: I have done this too, A.A Noman

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `url` look like this.

```
url: "{{url('')}}/api/users,
type: 'POST',
```

And your route should be placed in `route\api.php`. And your route should be look like this

```
Route::post('/users',       'ApiController@index');
```

And in your ApiController you write this code

```
class ApiController extends Controller{

    public function index(Request $request){

        $search = request('name');

        return User::where('name', 'LIKE', "$search%")->take(5)->pluck('name');

    }
 }
```

Comment: So the calls work without the library, now I have to make it work with the library.

Comment: It is not... I think it's because I'm placing it wrong in my code but I can't figure out what it is

Comment: I made edits, it works regular HTML but not in Laravel. Nothing is getting logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove "defer" from app.js in the app.blade.php file.